# Jquery fadetoggle

Tags: jquery, tooltip, fadein, fadeout

Im trying to use jquery fadetoggle for smooth fadein and fadeout. Everything works nice except one thing. When u hover the paragraph a tooltip fades in and when u leave paragraph then a tooltip fades out but when u hover paragraph and right after that u hover tooltip it will quickly fade out and fade back in. How can i get rid of this animation? I mean the tooltip shouldnt fade-in when i hover it. It should only fade in if i hover the paragraph

css

```
p{position: relative; cursor: default;}
#tooltip{display: none; position: absolute; top: -28px; left: 0px; padding: 1px 10px; border-radius: 13px; background: #3DD13D; color: #fff;}
```

html

```
<p>Text which has meta info when hovered<span id="tooltip">Hi im meta info</span></p>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('p').hover(function(){
        $('#tooltip').fadeToggle("500", "linear", "true")
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the animation before toggling it :

```
$('#tooltip').stop().fadeToggle("500", "linear", "true")
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/G6xzh/).